# Is it possible to multiply the results of two select statements?

Tags: sql, sqlite

If I have a select statement like this...

```
SELECT col1 FROM table WHERE col2=1
```

Which returns the results `1,2,3,4,5`.

And another select statement like this...

```
SELECT col1 FROM table WHERE col2=2
```

Which return the results `6,7,8,9,10`.

Is there a way to multiply the results of these two queries, so that a final result set of `6,14,24,36,50` is returned?

I've tried simple things like this.

```
SELECT (SELECT col1 FROM table WHERE col2=1) * (SELECT col1 FROM table WHERE col2=2)
```

But that didn't seem to work.

If it makes a difference, I'm using Sqlite, and the value types are REAL not INTEGER.

Comment: Not, it is not possible to do what you want.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So, the values that you see are unordered.  You need a way to define the relationship between the rows where you want the multiplication.

Comment: @GordonLinoff What if I add an ORDER BY to the statements?

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data and desired results.

Comment: You can do this, but you need to use row_number().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE ( thing real)
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (anotherThing real)

INSERT @Table1 (thing)
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5) 

INSERT @Table2 (anotherThing)
VALUES (6), (7), (8), (9), (10)
;

SELECT      T.thing * TT.anotherThing AS Multi
FROM        (
                SELECT  T.thing
                ,       (
                            SELECT  COUNT(1) RN
                            FROM    @Table1 AS T2
                            WHERE   T2.thing <= T.Thing
                        ) RN
                FROM        @Table1 AS T
            )AS T
INNER JOIN (
                SELECT      TT.anotherThing
                ,           (
                                SELECT  COUNT(1) RN 
                                FROM    @Table2 AS T2
                                WHERE   T2.anotherThing <= TT.anotherThing
                            ) RN
                FROM        @Table2 AS TT
            ) TT
        ON  TT.RN = T.RN
```

Result:

```
+-------+
| Multi |
+-------+
|     6 |
|    14 |
|    24 |
|    36 |
|    50 |
+-------+
```

The example probably won't work in sqlite, I wrote it in sql server. [This](https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-5954f8eee0b2153bj4ifoh84) shows it works on sqlite.